# I'm trying to git push HEAD but it shows error: remote: Repository not found

Tags: git, github, push

I tried to push my repo despite the commits changed to the HEAD

```
(base) apples-MacBook-Pro:Trying to clone notionso note taking app with django and reac apple$ git branch
* (HEAD detached at 7da824b)
  master
```

that is my situation where I got my commit in `(HEAD detached at 7da824b)` instead of `master`

```
(base) apples-MacBook-Pro:Trying to clone notionso note taking app with django and reac apple$ git push origin development
error: src refspec development does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/aliplutus/Trying-to-clone-notionso-note-taking-app-with-django-and-reac.git'
(base) apples-MacBook-Pro:Trying to clone notionso note taking app with django and reac apple$ git push -u origin master
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/aliplutus/Trying-to-clone-notionso-note-taking-app-with-django-and-reac.git/' not found
(base) apples-MacBook-Pro:Trying to clone notionso note taking app with django and reac apple$ git push -u origin development
error: src refspec development does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/aliplutus/Trying-to-clone-notionso-note-taking-app-with-django-and-reac.git'
(base) apples-MacBook-Pro:Trying to clone notionso note taking app with django and reac apple$
```

these are the ways that I tried and I got error says `Repository not found`

```
error: src refspec development does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/aliplutus/Trying-to-clone-notionso-note-taking-app-with-django-and-reac.git'
```

I treid `git push -u origin master` and `git push -u origin head` and `git push -u origin HEAD` and `git push -u origin development`

Comment: Note that you are working in "detached HEAD" mode. This is not a normal way to work (although it does occur during an in-progress `git rebase`).

Answer (score 1):

Close you need to specify destination

```
git push origin HEAD:master
```

Comment: @ EncryptedWatermelon
i got the same err
```
django and reac apple$ git push origin HEAD:master

remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/aliplutus/Trying-to-clone-notionso-note-taking-app-with-django-and-reac.git/' not found
```